# Constraining Eager Loads distinct not working

Tags: laravel-5

```
Department::with(['dispatches' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT dispatchedItem'));
        }])->get();
```

All I am trying to do here is fetch the distinct values but its result nothing (empty array for all my department). Why is this?

Comment: The fact that no results are returned for your Departmets would suggest that your `Department` model may map to an empty database table. Using `with` returns all results of `Department` along with results of `dispataches` that fit your query constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answered my question once a again. All I had to do was put brackets after the discount. This is because I was calling a query builder method on a collection and it was not working so when you place the brackets you get a query builder instance to use your query builder methods. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your code that worked for you which can help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this without the `DB::raw()` statement with the `->distinct()` function.

```
Department::with(['dispatches' => function ($query) {
            $query->distinct('dispatchedItem'));
        }])->get();
```

Comment: i did that but it returned all duplicates when I counted them

Comment: Department::with(['dispatches' => function ($query) {
                  $query->groupBy('dispatches.dispatchedItem');
      }])->get();

This then gives me inconsistent values with those that have duplicates

Comment: If you are wanting to count afterwards, try my `$query->distinct('dispatchedItem')->count());`

Comment: I do count them but they dont return distinct values they return all values